# Group Rows by Date

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have been asked to group transactions that have occurred within two minutes of one another into separate "date groups". I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around how to split the data by minutes.

I wrote a test table below along with expected "date groups"

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpData
(ID int,actionDt datetime)

INSERT INTO #tmpData
(ID,actionDt)
VALUES
(1, '7/22/2021 9:51'),
(1, '7/22/2021 9:52'),
(1, '7/22/2021 9:55'),
(1, '7/22/2021 9:56'),
(1, '7/22/2021 9:57'),
(1, '7/22/2021 9:58'),
(1, '7/22/2021 10:00'),
(1, '7/22/2021 10:10'),
(2, '7/22/2021 8:38'),
(2, '7/22/2021 8:39'),
(2, '7/22/2021 8:40'),
(2, '7/22/2021 12:05')
```

the expected "date groups" should be

| id | DtGroup |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/22/2021 9:51 |
| 1 | 7/22/2021 9:55 |
| 1 | 7/22/2021 9:58 |
| 1 | 7/22/2021 10:10 |
| 2 | 7/22/2021 8:38 |
| 2 | 7/22/2021 12:05 |

I wrote the below which gets close but the timestamps 9:58 and 10:00 for ID 1 should be their own date group.

```
;with resultSet AS
(
    SELECT a.id, a.actiondt, a.diff  FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            id, 
            actiondt, 
            diff = datediff(mi,lag(actiondt) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY actiondt),actiondt)
        FROM #tmpdata
    ) AS a 
    WHERE diff IS NULL OR diff > 2
)


SELECT 
    t.id, 
    t.actiondt AS currDt, 
    resultset.actiondt AS DtGrp
from #tmpdata t
left JOIN resultset
on t.id = resultset.id 
    and t.actiondt between dateadd(mi,-2,resultset.actiondt) and dateadd(mi,2,resultset.actiondt)
```

Comment: So you just want the starting row of each group? Why is `7/22/2021 9:58` included, the previous row is `7/22/2021 9:57`

Comment: @Charlieface 9:58 is more than two minutes from the previous Date Group that occurred at 9:55. The user wants the actions grouped into two minutes intervals :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the logic 2 minutes or greater between actionDt? If so should the expected results be the following? Otherwise, I don't understand your expected results to try to help.

```
(1, '7/22/2021 9:51'),
(1, '7/22/2021 9:55'),
(1, '7/22/2021 9:57'),
(1, '7/22/2021 10:00'),
(1, '7/22/2021 10:10'),

(2, '7/22/2021 8:38'),
(2, '7/22/2021 8:40'),
(2, '7/22/2021 12:05')
```

This will give you the above results.

```
declare @Count int, 
@LoopCount int,
@PrevMinutes int,
@CurrentMinutes int,
@NextMinutes int,
@PrevFlag int,
@Flag int

;with dID as (
    select distinct id,
    actiondt
    from #tmpData
)

select 
identity(int,1,1) RowNo, 
d.id as Grp,
d.actiondt, 
lag(DATEPART(mi, d.actiondt), 1,0) over (order by d.actiondt) as PrevMinutes,
DATEPART(mi, d.actiondt) as CurrentMinutes,
lead(DATEPART(mi, d.actiondt), 1,0) over (order by d.actiondt) as NextMinutes,
0 as  flag
into #Temp
from #tmpData d
full outer join dID on d.id = dID.id
                    and d.actiondt = dID.actiondt
order by d.id, actiondt 

select @Count = @@RowCount 
set @LoopCount = 1 

while @LoopCount <= @Count 
begin 
    set @PrevMinutes = (select PrevMinutes from #Temp where RowNo = @LoopCount)
    set @CurrentMinutes = (select CurrentMinutes from #Temp where RowNo = @LoopCount)
    set @NextMinutes = (select NextMinutes from #Temp where RowNo = @LoopCount)
    set @Flag = (select flag from #Temp where RowNo = @LoopCount)
    set @PrevFlag = (select flag from #Temp where RowNo = @LoopCount - 1)
    
    if (@LoopCount = 1)
    begin
        update #Temp
        set flag = 1 
        where RowNo = 1
    end
    else if (abs(@PrevMinutes - @CurrentMinutes) >= 2)
    begin
        update #Temp
        set flag = 1 
        where RowNo = @LoopCount
    end
    else if (@PrevFlag = 0 and @Flag = 0)
    begin
        update #Temp
        set flag = 1 
        where RowNo = @LoopCount
    end

    set @LoopCount=@LoopCount + 1 
end 

select Grp as id,
actiondt
from #Temp
where flag = 1
```

Comment: you're right.  I misinterpreted my expected result set.  The logic is actually two minutes or greater. I'll run with your result. Thank you for your help!